# How Can I make activities behavior like this

Tags: android, android-activity

**HI DEVELOPERS**,

The Question:

I have 5 activities in my app;
I want to make them behavior like this :

[image]

What I tried:

A -> C (create new one)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

A -> B (create new one)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

B -> C (create new one)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

C -> D (**I want to use existing in stack**)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
D.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

C -> E (**I want to use existing in stack**)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), E.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

D -> C (**I want to use existing in stack**)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_a,
    R.anim.right_to_left_b);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

E -> C (**I want to use existing in stack**)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_a,
    R.anim.right_to_left_b);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This is not working because the activities in stack are not arranged correct.

*The problem is I dont know how to go from C to B or A when back key pressed,Now when I push back key in C,It goes to D or E!*

**THIS IS THE EXACT THING I WANT:**

```
A->B when a button pressed,create new B
B->A when back key pressed,finish B
A->C when a button pressed,create new C
C->A when back key pressed,finish C
B->C when a button pressed,create new C
C->B when back key pressed,finish C

C->E when a button pressed,create new E if not exist otherwise use existing one
E->C when back key pressed,use existing one
C->D when a button pressed,create new D if not exist otherwise use existing one
D->C when back key pressed,use existing one
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.  A to B to C to D or A to B to C to E. Now back E to C to A by clearing back stack on back press. D to C to B to A

Comment: When you got from A To B and press back button activity B is popped from stack and destroyed. previous activity in stack ie A takes focus. A to B To C on back press in C you can go to A by clearing back stack.

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan,Can you show me the exact way to clear backstack programatically? my problem is D and E coz their are in stack yet when back key pressed in C

Comment: You need to override the `onBackPressed()` methods of your activities to start whatever you want and not the parent of the activity. Still, I would rethink the flow of your application as this will get really messy, especially of you want to transfer data across activities.

Comment: @milson when you back press say in activity E you go back to C. Activity E is popped an destroyed. Study the topic on backstack in the link provided in the above comment

Comment: @Raghunandan, no no I want to make D and E stay in stack coz the UI in D and E must not change when back key pressed in them,Also about C the UI must not change when it goes to D or E but when back key pressed not important it destroyed or not

Comment: when back pressed activity is popped from stack and destroyed.

Comment: So with the note I've added What should I do to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A to B To C. In C you press back button by default will goto B by calling finish().Activity C is popped from the stack an destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is B that takes focus. This is the default functionality.

Since you asked how to clear backstack , you can use the below

Say in activity C press back button you need to goto A you can use the below.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // clear back stack
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
return;
    }
```

Comment: as I mentioned,the problem is arranging back stack.Assume this situation: in C the back key pressed and D and E are in stack yet so it goes to D or E instead of B or A for example

Answer (score 0):

you should try `public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`
view this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused from your test but I think that the problem is on the way you `Override onBackPressed()`

When you override the onBackPressed without `super.onBackPressed();` or `this.finish();` you actually do not allow the native system action to remove current activity from the stack.

As a result there is an inconsistency between back button in hole application. At activities A, B, C works as expected, whereas at D, E the back button creates new activities without destroying the existing. So if I am not mistaken a user is being trapped in your app!?

To edit your code I fast fix may be:

D -> C (I want to use existing in stack)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_a,
    R.anim.right_to_left_b);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

E -> C (I want to use existing in stack)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), C.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_a,
    R.anim.right_to_left_b);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```